# ImageView setMargins doesn't work

Tags: android, imageview

I have a FrameLayout that has 2 images, a big one that that fills the FrameLayout and a very small one that I want to move around.

I try to move the small one like this:
xml file

```
   <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/layTrackMap"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:visibility="gone">

         <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgTrackMap" 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               />

         <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgPosition" 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/position" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"

               />

         </FrameLayout>
```

and the code:

```
imgPosition = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgPosition);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    //Neither this:
    //lp.setMargins(30, 20, 0, 0);

    //Or this
    lp.leftMargin=30;
    lp.topMargin=80;

    imgPosition.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

The small image doesn't move. I want to be able to move the small image around in layout.

**LATER EDIT:
After trying several suggestions I came to the conclusion that is simpler to just make a custom View and override onDraw to do the job.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything in a FrameLayout is fixed to the top left and can't be moved, even by setting margins. But you can get the same result by using padding...

```
imgPosition.setPadding(30, 80, 0, 0);
```

Comment: This works in theory. However, if you want to add a background drawable (e.g. to indicate your image is selected) this will stretch it. The better solution is to define your LayoutParam object with margins and to set the gravity as Fede indicated. Or, do the custom view if you would rather go that route.

Answer (score 11):

You should also set the gravity in order to use margins:

```
lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
```

Comment: For some reason, only setting the gravity in code like this solved the problem for me; oddly, setting the gravity in the XML layout didn't.

Answer (score 3):

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
imgPosition1.setLayoutParams(lp);  

lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;    
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
imgPosition2.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

i did manage to use setMargin just like a regular `setPadding`..however you have to set a new layout parameter for every `imageview` you like to set a margin